# How would you create a horizontal toc?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, diagrams

I'm trying to create a horizontal table of contents, but have no clue how I should start. My end goal would be something like this:

[image]

I have some experience with latex, but unfortunately I am lacking any clue how to automate this process. Therefore I would really appreciate any input how I should or can start this endeavour.

Comment: What class of document do you use? I dn't understand the notion of ‘Current Title’  in a table of contents.

Comment: I should have mentioned it. It is for a presentation and should be used in the beamer context.

Comment: Do you need to use the toc system, or are you willing to retype the titles?

Comment: I would really appreciate a command like this \ownhortoc and \ownhortoc[current]. If i manually input the titles, I could ether use lualtex in combination with TikZ or I could automate the generation of an pdf or png with another program. Both actions would lead to a semiautomatic solution, which is prone to errors. At the Moment it would even help, if there is a way to get the tiles / chapter names in lualtex. If anybody knows something in that regard or has another solution, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, the toc system consists of first writing \@writefile{toc} commands in the aux file.  The toc file is only created if \tableofcontents in used.  So you need to modify \@writefile to either extract the info needed of go ahead and write the toc file without \tableofcontents.

Comment: Actually, if you are only doing chapter names you might want to just modify the \chapter macro to write your own commands to the aux file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Beamer** has its own mechanism to create TOC.

Basically, every time you call `\tableofcontents[options]`, **Beamer** includes the same `.toc` file once. The only difference is that, with different `options`, **Beamer** will change the way it applies styles to the content of the `.toc` file.

After all, **Beamer** provides you some beamer templates such as `subsection in toc` and `subsection in toc shaded` so you can decide the final apparent of normal/shaded [[sub]sub]section.

Let me show you an example. This is how normal TOC looks like

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}

\section{PGF}
    \subsection{Arrow Keys}
        \subsubsection{Length}
        \subsubsection{Width}
    \subsection{Decoration}
        \subsubsection{Amplitude}
        \subsubsection{Radius}
    \subsection{Text}
        \subsubsection{Left}
        \subsubsection{Right}
\section{TikZ}
    \subsection{CS}
        \subsubsection{Node}
        \subsubsection{Solution}
    \subsection{External}
        \subsubsection{Optimize}
        \subsubsection{Prefix}
    \subsection{Graphs}
        \subsubsection{Quick}
        \subsubsection{Simple}
\section{PGFPLOTS}
    \subsection{Table}
        \subsubsection{Col sep}
        \subsubsection{Row sep}
    \subsection{Group}
        \subsubsection{Group name}
        \subsubsection{Group size}
    \subsection{Mesh}
        \subsubsection{Check}
        \subsubsection{Odering}

\frame{{Normal TOC}
    \begin{multicols}2\tableofcontents\end{multicols}
}
\frame{{Normal TOC}
    \begin{multicols}2\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{multicols}
}
\frame{{Normal TOC}
    \begin{multicols}2\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]\end{multicols}
}
```

And this is how TOC looks like if you build those templates by `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]`

[image]

```
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={remember picture,overlay,scale=.3}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}{tikz}{
    \tikz\path(temp node)+(0,-1)node(temp node){}+(0,0)node[right]{\inserttocsection};
}
\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc shaded}{tikz}[1][.2]{
    \tikz\path(temp node)+(0,-1)node(temp node){}+(0,0)node[right,opacity=#1]{\inserttocsection};
}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc}{tikz}{
    \tikz\path(temp node)+(0,-1)node(temp node){}+(6,0)node[right]{\inserttocsubsection};
}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc shaded}{tikz}[1][.2]{
    \tikz\path(temp node)+(0,-1)node(temp node){}+(6,0)node[right,opacity=#1]{\inserttocsubsection};
}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsubsection in toc}{tikz}{
    \tikz\path(temp node)+(0,-1)node(temp node){}+(12,0)node[right]{\inserttocsubsubsection};
}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsubsection in toc shaded}{tikz}[1][.2]{
    \tikz\path(temp node)+(0,-1)node(temp node){}+(12,0)node[right,opacity=#1]{\inserttocsubsubsection};
}

\frame{{Ti\emph kZ TOC}
    \tikz\path(current page.north west)+(12,-1)node(temp node){};\tableofcontents
}
\frame{{Ti\emph kZ TOC}
    \tikz\path(current page.north west)+(12,-1)node(temp node){};\tableofcontents[currentsection]
}
\frame{{Ti\emph kZ TOC}
    \tikz\path(current page.north west)+(12,-1)node(temp node){};\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
}
```

With even more works, you can achieve

[image]

```
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={remember picture,overlay,scale=1},
    Signal/.style={fill,signal,signal from=west,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm},
    Secnal/.style={shift={(0,-.5)},right,rotate=-70,opacity=#1},
    Subsecnal/.style={below right,rotate=-60,opacity=#1},
    Subsubsecnal/.style={below right,rotate=-50,opacity=#1},
}

\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}{fabulous}{
    \tikz\path(temp section)+(3,0)node[Signal,blue](temp section){}node[Secnal= 1](true section){\inserttocsection}(true section.north east)node(temp subsection){};
}
\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc shaded}{fabulous}[1][.5]{
    \tikz\path(temp section)+(3,0)node[Signal,gray](temp section){}node[Secnal=#1](true section){\inserttocsection}(true section.north east)node(temp subsection){};
}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc}{fabulous}{
    \tikz\path(temp subsection)node[Subsecnal= 1](true subsection){$>$\inserttocsubsection}(true subsection.south west)node(temp subsection){}(true subsection.north east)node(temp subsubsection){};
}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc shaded}{fabulous}[1][.2]{
    \tikz\path(temp subsection)node[Subsecnal=#1](true subsection){$>$\inserttocsubsection}(true subsection.south west)node(temp subsection){}(true subsection.north east)node(temp subsubsection){};
}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsubsection in toc}{fabulous}{
    \tikz\path(temp subsubsection)node[Subsubsecnal= 1](true subsubsection){$-$\inserttocsubsubsection}(true subsubsection.north east)node(temp subsubsection){};
}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsubsection in toc shaded}{fabulous}[1][.2]{
    \tikz\path(temp subsubsection)node[Subsubsecnal=#1](true subsubsection){$-$\inserttocsubsubsection}(true subsubsection.north east)node(temp subsubsection){};
}

\frame{{Fabulous TOC}
    \tikz\path(current page.north west)+(0,-2)node(temp section){};\tableofcontents
}
\frame{{Fabulous TOC}
    \tikz\path(current page.north west)+(0,-2)node(temp section){};\tableofcontents[currentsection]
}
\frame{{Fabulous TOC}
    \tikz\path(current page.north west)+(0,-2)node(temp section){};\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
}


\end{document}
```