# Customize the toc in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, table-of-contents, templates

I want to create the following template for the `\tableofcontents` in `beamer`.
[image]

I am able to generate the code for the list of `sections` and `subsections` with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{family*=qag, size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,line width=0pt]
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,0);
        \node[anchor=base east] at (.7\textwidth,0) { \inserttocsubsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,line width=0pt]
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,0);
        \node[anchor=base east] at (.7\textwidth,0) { \inserttocsection};
        \node[anchor=base west] at (.7\textwidth+4ex+2.2ex,0){\inserttocsectionnumber};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}{Some frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I do not find a smart way to insert the vertical line. If I use the `background` template, I can do it but the positioning is not easy (and strongly depends on the `aspectratio` and the `margins`). The same happens with `overlay` in `tikzpicture`. I tried to find a way to enclose the `section in toc` templates within a `tikzpicture` and define each template as a collection of nodes, but it seems `\tableofcontets` is more complex than I thought. For example, using `\patchcmd` is not a good choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341214/how-to-generate-a-toc-frame-that-have-been-customized-using-tikz

Answer (score 0):

You could label the nodes and then draw your line from the first to the last section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{family*=qag, size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,line width=0pt]
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,0);
        \node[anchor=base east] at (.7\textwidth,0) { \inserttocsubsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,line width=0pt,remember picture]
        \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,0);
        \node[anchor=base east] (toc-\inserttocsectionnumber) at (.7\textwidth,0) { \inserttocsection};
        \node[anchor=base west] at (.7\textwidth+4ex+2.2ex,0){\inserttocsectionnumber};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,line width=0.1cm] ([xshift=4.1ex,yshift=2ex]toc-1.north east) -- ([xshift=4.1ex,yshift=-2ex]toc-\the\beamer@sectionmax.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Third Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your last section is going to include subsections, you could label them as well and use https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1987#a2230 to figure out the last subsection number.