# {beamer} toc as equally sized boxes in rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, table-of-contents

The **corporate identity** of my company defines the *table of content* in presentations as equally sized shaped boxes so that 5 of them fit in a row even if there are less, and more go into the next line. The section titles should *word wrap* inside this boxes as sown in the picture:
[image: desired output]

At most 3 rows limiting to 15 sections need to be supported.

I would be able to create this manually for each presentation using `{tikz}` but unfortunately I have no clue how to approach  a TOC template to get this automatically from `\section` entries.

It would be acceptable if "unused" boxes would be rendered as empty boxes with gray background limiting the TOC to 15 entries in total.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260647/134144 could help you getting started.

Comment: @leandriis thanks, this looks quite promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the answer to [this question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590365/beamer-toc-like-standard-paragraph).

In addition to the `{multicol}` approach I define the beamer template for *sections in TOC* to use `\parbox` with fixed height.

The final shape is set using `{tikz}` nodes with a background image (not shown here).

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{% 
     \colorbox{yellow}{
        \parbox[t][3.5em]{.2\textwidth}{
            \inserttocsectionnumber\\
            \parbox[c][2.5em]{.2\textwidth}{
                \inserttocsection
            }   
         }   
     }
}
\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section1 gwerrgtw}
    \section{Section2 gwerrgtw}
    \section{Section3 }
    \section{Section4}
    \section{Section gwerrgtw5}
    \section{Section6}
    \section{Section7 gwerrgtw}
    
    \frame{{TOC}
    %% first TOC row
                \begin{multicols}{4}  
                    \vspace*{-.5em} % first column has a vertical "indent" I could not come around otherwise
                
                    \tableofcontents[sections=1-4]  
                \end{multicols}
    
    %% second TOC row
                \begin{multicols}{4}  
                    \vspace*{-.5em} % first column has a vertical "indent" I could not come around otherwise
                
                    \tableofcontents[sections=5-8]  
                \end{multicols}
    
    %% third TOC row, not used in this example due to leck of sections...
                \begin{multicols}{4}  
                    \vspace*{-.5em} % first column has a vertical "indent" I could not come around otherwise
                
                    \tableofcontents[sections=9-12]  
                \end{multicols}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]