# {beamer} TOC like standard paragraph

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

The TOC in LaTeX seams to be an *itemize* environment.

Is it possible to change that in `{beamer}`, so that the TOC renders like an standard paragraph including line beaks if it gets longer than `\linewidth`?

My desired output should look like this:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\section{Section2}
\section{Section3}
\section{Section4}
\section{Section5}
\section{Section6}
\section{Section7}


\frame{{TOC}
    \tableofcontents
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I did not find the exact solution, but the second best was the use of the `{multicol}` package.</strike>
The solution is to combine multiple `{multicol}` parts along wit the restriction of `\tableofcontents` to certain sections:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section1}
    \section{Section2}
    \section{Section3}
    \section{Section4}
    \section{Section5}
    \section{Section6}
    \section{Section7}
    
    \frame{{TOC}
    %% first TOC row
                \begin{multicols}{4}  
                    \vspace*{-.5em} % first column has a vertical "indent" I could not come around otherwise
                
                    \tableofcontents[sections=1-4]  
                \end{multicols}
    
    %% second TOC row
                \begin{multicols}{4}  
                    \vspace*{-.5em} % first column has a vertical "indent" I could not come around otherwise
                
                    \tableofcontents[sections=5-8]  
                \end{multicols}
    
    %% third TOC row
                \begin{multicols}{4}  
                    \vspace*{-.5em} % first column has a vertical "indent" I could not come around otherwise
                
                    \tableofcontents[sections=9-12]  
                \end{multicols}

    }
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]